# Mailgun for receiving emails (rackspace)

Tags: email, email-server, rackspace

Disclaimer: I am a total server noob so this might be a very stupid question.

If I am using Mailgun as my email service for my domain, where do I setup mailboxes for the domain? ie. some.user@mydomain.com

According to Mailgun, mailboxes are a legacy feature no longer supported. So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the point of Mailgun. It is not intended to replace a normal e-mail infrastructure. If you want that, you need something like Google Apps for Business.

Mailgun is intended for sending and receiving automated e-mails. For example, you might set up e-mails to support@example.com to be processed by a script to add them to your ticket system.

Comment: Okay, that makes perfect sense. So I still need to use something like a Rackspace email server for pop/smtp, and use mailgun for automated emails - like a monthly newsletter to customers, etc?

Comment: For a newsletter you'd be better with a bulk e-mail solution like Mailchimp or Campaign Monitor. Mailgun's sending is more for "here's your password" - transactional e-mails to single recipients.

Comment: Familiar with both Mailchimp and Campaign Monitor. It would seem reading "free to Rackspace users" has sent me in the totally wrong direction. Thanks for the info / advice.